# Missing launcher icon after upgrading to mimap

Tags: android, drawable, android-launcher, mipmaps

I updated my project `ic_launcher` icon from `drawable` to `mipmap` with the following configuration:

**Old project:**

```
drawable
- ic_launcher.png(5)
-- ic_launcher.png(hdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(mdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(xhdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(xxhdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(xxxhdpi)
```

Manifest `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

**New project:**

```
mipmap
- ic_launcher.png(5)
-- ic_launcher.png(hdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(mdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(xhdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(xxhdpi)
-- ic_launcher.png(xxxhdpi)
```

Manifest: `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

After a new release of my application I had a bad surprise, users that made the update to the new version had all the default android icon instead of the app icon provided.

How to be able to make this transition working? Because I used every tricks without any outputs.

Comment: Ask them to reboot their device. Or, ask them to check the icon in your app's screen in Settings. Their home screen may have cached the old resource ID.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your quick answer. That could be a solution but you can't ask all your users to make such a manipulation. I'm trying to fix that issue by providing a new application update directly.

Comment: "That could be a solution but you can't ask all your users to make such a manipulation" -- changing anything associated with your home screen launcher (icon, caption, activity to be launched, etc.) is risky for this very reason.